# Group homomorphism for cohomology group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, spectral-sequences

Inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260699/short-exact-sequence-and-cohomology-group), I wonder, for a short exact sequence for some finite groups $A,B,C$, (I am happy to consider Lie groups too)
$$1\to A \to B \to C \to 1,$$
whether there are generic group homomorphism for their cohomology groups?

$$H^d(B,M) \to H^d(A,M)?$$

$$H^d(B,M) \to H^d(C,M)?$$

$$H^d(C,M) \to H^d(B,M)?$$

$$H^d(A,M) \to H^d(B,M)?$$

For any $d$ or certain $d$?

Here $M$ can be $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I know essentially nothing about group cohomology, but any time I've seen cohomology used, it's been contravariantly functorial.  In particular, I would be shocked if the answer is "NO" for your first and third questions for any integer $d$, regardless of what allowable group $M$ denotes.

Comment: Thanks, can you write an answer to explain why?

Comment: As I said, I know nothing about group cohomology.  I just know a bit of mathematical culture - the word "cohomology" is typically (always?) reserved for some kind on contravariant functor.  Of course, you may define a term however you want whenever you want, so this isn't a true answer to your question.  Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: The contravariant homomorphisms exist for any $d$ and any $M$ (I mention this at the end of my answer to the post you linked), and you can just define them on the cochain level.  Perhaps surprisingly, if $G \to H$ is such that $G$ has finite index in $H$, then the covariant homomorphisms also exist.