# Are there any non-trivial group extensions of $SU(N)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence, characteristic-classes, group-extensions

> Are there any non-trivial group extensions of $SU(N)$?
>
> If not, can one show/prove there are no non-trivial group extensions of $SU(N)$?

It is possibly partial related to the homotopy group property. Or one can try to argue from the exact sequence.

Proof/Show: Let us call $Q=SU(N)$. If the above claim is true, namely, we cannot find some larger $G$ with its normal subgroup $N$, such that $G/N=Q$. Here what we mean by "non-trivial" means that a non-identity normal $N \neq 1$, and there the $G$ is not a product group (i.e. $G \neq Q \times N)$, where $Q=SU(N)$.

p.s. The statement has been corrected for clarity, please upvoting it for the sake of getting better discussions/attentions.

Comment: What do you mean by nontrivial? The direct product of $SU(n)$ with any other group will be a nontrivial extension. If by nontrivial you mean that aren't direct or semidirect products?

Comment: Yes, by nontrivial I mean that aren't direct products, but may be semidirect products, or act projectively.

Comment: Are you familiar with group cohomology?

Comment: Thanks, I know for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260699/short-exact-sequence-and-cohomology-group

Comment: p.s. Justin made a comment earlier that $U(N)/SU(N)=U(1)$, but it was not quite correct to my case because I am looking for $G/N=SU(N)$ for some non-product group $G \neq N \times SU(N)$.

Comment: I believe that my questions is very motivated and well-defined.

Comment: Could you edit the question? Non-trivial doesn't mean what you want it to mean in this context. I would of just said "Group extensions that are not direct products" or whatever. This way you can clear up some of the confusion caused.

Comment: $U(n)$ is not, as a group, a product $S^1 \times SU(n)$. If you allow the extension to have higher dimension then that does give an example. I don't know the answer for finite groups.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I am looking for $1 \to N \to G \to SU(N) \to 1$, not the other way you mentioned.